# Should my function return a self reference or a new copy of self?

Tags: class, object, rust, clone

```
use Vec3::Vec3;

struct Matrix3x3
{
    _array: [f64; 9],
}

impl Matrix3x3
{
    pub fn new(m: [f64; 9]) -> Self
    {
        Matrix3x3 { _array: m}
    }

    pub fn from_column_vectors(&self, cx: &Vec3, cy: &Vec3, cz: &Vec3) -> Matrix3x3
    {
        let cx1 = cx.normalized();
        let cy1 = cy.normalized();
        let cz1 = cz.normalized();

        self._array[0] = cx1.x;
        self._array[1] = cx1.y;
        self._array[2] = cx1.z;

        self._array[3] = cy1.x;
        self._array[4] = cy1.y;
        self._array[5] = cy1.z;

        self._array[6] = cz1.x;
        self._array[7] = cz1.y;
        self._array[8] = cz1.z;

        return Matrix3x3::new(self._array);
    }

    pub fn from_row_vectors(&self, rx: &Vec3, ry: &Vec3, rz: &Vec3) -> &Matrix3x3
    {
        let cx1 = rx.normalized();
        let cy1 = ry.normalized();
        let cz1 = rz.normalized();

        self._array[0] = cx1.x;
        self._array[1] = cy1.x;
        self._array[2] = cz1.x;

        self._array[3] = cx1.y;
        self._array[4] = cy1.y;
        self._array[5] = cz1.y;

        self._array[6] = cx1.z;
        self._array[7] = cy1.z;
        self._array[8] = cz1.z;

        return self;
    }
}
```

In the above source code, `from_column_vectors()` returns a copy of self as a new object. On the other hand, `from_row_vectors()` returns a reference to the self.

Which option should I practice in the case of performance-critical applications?

Explain why.

Comment: Benchmark. This is the only answer.

Comment: In the first function you mutate `self` (`&mut` is required, by the way), **and** you return a new matrix; this is probably not want you intended. In the second function, `&mut self` is required to mutate in-place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these should return a new value because neither do anything with whatever was already in `*self`.  In fact, there shouldn't even be any `self` parameter to begin with, as these are clearly named to be constructor functions.

If one wants to clobber an existing `Matrix3x3` then they can just assign from the result of calling one of these functions.  If you are concerned about performance, not that RVO should elide the copy, and this is something you can test by compiling with optimizations and inspecting the generated assembly.

For example:

```
struct Matrix3x3
{
    _array: [f64; 9],
}

impl Matrix3x3
{
    pub fn new(m: [f64; 9]) -> Self
    {
        Matrix3x3 { _array: m }
    }

    pub fn from_column_vectors(cx: &Vec3, cy: &Vec3, cz: &Vec3) -> Self
    {
        let cx1 = cx.normalized();
        let cy1 = cy.normalized();
        let cz1 = cz.normalized();
        
        Self::new([
            cx1.x, cx1.y, cx1.z,
            cy1.x, cy1.y, cy1.z,
            cz1.x, cz1.y, cz1.z,
        ])
    }

    pub fn from_row_vectors(rx: &Vec3, ry: &Vec3, rz: &Vec3) -> Self
    {
        let rx1 = rx.normalized();
        let ry1 = ry.normalized();
        let rz1 = rz.normalized();
        
        Self::new([
            rx1.x, ry1.x, rz1.x,
            rx1.y, ry1.y, rz1.y,
            rx1.z, ry1.z, rz1.z,
        ])
    }
}
```

Then, if someone wants to overwrite an existing value, they can:

```
let mut x: Matrix3x3 = todo!();
x = Matrix3x3::from_column_vectors(todo!(), todo!(), todo!());
```

Comment: plz, remove the name `RotoTranslation.` It was a mistake. It should be `Matrix3x3` instead.

Comment: Why isn't there any `return` statement?

Comment: @user366312 If the last statement in a block is an expression that lacks a terminating `;` then that expression becomes the value of the block. In a function, this becomes the return value, but it's not limited to just functions. This is why Rust doesn't have a ternary operator (`a ? b : c`) because this behavior also applies to `if` blocks, so in Rust you would say `if a { b } else { c }`.